# Spacing inconsistency on method invocation in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a class with getter/setter:

```
class Person {
    private var _age = 0

    //getter
    def age = _age

    //setter
    def age_=(value: Int): Unit = _age = value

    def echo(x: String): Unit = println(x)
}
```

I did some testing:

```
val p = new Person()
//invoke age setter method
p.age =(2)
p age = 11
p.age = 8-4

// invoke echo method
p.echo("Hello")
p echo "Scala"
p.echo "Johnson"    //compile error here
```

So I got compile error at:

```
p.echo "Johnson"
```

with error message:

```
Error:(84, 16) ';' expected but string literal found.
        p.echo "Johnson"    //compile error here (why scala?)
               ^
```

Why `p.age = 8-4` works fine but I got error on `p.echo "Johnson"`? Is it because `_=` in `def age_=` ?

**UPDATE:**

I did an experiment:

```
class Person {

    ...

    def echo = "Ginger"
    def echo_=(x: String): Unit = println(x)
}
```

Then changed the `echo` method calling:

```
p.echo= ("Hello")
p echo= "Scala"
p.echo= "Johnson"
```

They works fine. But if I removed `def echo = "Ginger"`, I will get compile error.

So based on this observation, I got conclusion: the "magic" of setter method depends on the getter method. If no getter method defined, the magic vanished.

But that means I can't create a setter (write only) method ??

Comment: Answer about `_`: it is required to syntactically create an identifier. Each symbol (non-alnum char) should be separated by at least one `_` from alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @GáborBakos: thanks. But it seems the underscore only can be used once, because when I tried this: `val x_=_x  = 20`, I got compile error. I also have some more questions about it, I think I better make a separate question for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the point-free scala syntax only lets you drop the parentheses if you also drop the dot:

```
1 + 2   // 3
1.+(2)  // 3

1.+ 2
// <console>:1: error: ';' expected but integer literal found.
//   1.+ 2
//       ^
```

Basically it thinks you're trying to call a no-arg method `echo`, and then you have a random string literal following it.

Comment: That's a completely different, specially-handled syntax.  It's not as if `age` is a method name and `=` is the argument.  The compiler is transforming it into `p.age_=(8-4)`, not `p.age(=)...`.

Comment: See my updated question. So all of this are coming from **scala's magic**?

Comment: Setter/getter and assignment: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions and http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignments